# How do I delete year month and date, display only time on python

Tags: python

I have to convert the object to DateTime. However, it shows a year, month, and day at the front. So how can I display only time?

**f1['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(f1['Time'], format = '%H:%M:%S.%f')
f1['Time']**

It shows:

**0    1900-01-01 01:32:03.897**

**1    1900-01-01 02:02:34.598**

**2    1900-01-01 01:34:31.421**

What I want is time only, like this:

**0    01:32:03.897**

**1    02:02:34.598**

**2    01:34:31.421**

Answer (score 1):

For 24h format :

```
print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%X"))
```

For 12h formart with am/pm :

```
print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M:%S %p"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please include your code in your post and not in a screenshot.

But also, did you try using

```
datetime.time
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're successfully converting the data to datetime objects. What is being shown in the output is the string representation of the date.

The format string you passed to `pd.to_datetime` is just for parsing the dates. It does not affect their internal data. If you only need strings, you should call `.strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")` for each date object in your collection.